# Detection angle of tilt and rotation of images on Android

Tags: android, eclipse, image-processing, leptonica

i create Android apps, that need skew angle detection. When image input in a slanting position after the image is processed using that functions, it will turn into a perpendicular position.

So, i use Leptonica (tess-two library) to achieve that, i used FindSkew() function here is my piece source code :

```
// get bitmap picture
BitmapFactory.Options PictureOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
PengaturanGambarCapture.inSampleSize = 2;    
Image = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length, PictureOptions);

// get skew angle value 
float SkewValue = Skew.findSkew(ReadFile.readBitmap(Image));

// rotate bitmap using matrix
int w = Image.getWidth();
int h = Image.getHeight();
Matrix MatrixSkew = new Matrix();
MatrixSkew.postRotate(SkewValue);
Bitmap BitmapSkew = Bitmap.createBitmap(Image, 0, 0, w, h, MatrixSkew, true);

// set BitmapSkew to imageview 
OutputImage.setImageBitmap(BitmapSkew);
```

But when it run does not happen, ... the picture still in a tilted position. What's my mistake ??? Would you help me to fix it or you have other ways to rotate tilted images automatically. Thank you

Comment: I am also having this same problem , please suggest me a solution.

Comment: Me too,... it seems like, there's no one using that function. I've been trying till now, but it the result still failure